# MQTT connection through ESP01 8266

Tags: c++, arduino, localhost, esp8266, mosquitto

I'm trying to establish a connection with my m
Mosquitto server through an ESP01 8266. I installed Mosquitto on my computer and started it with Brew.

The problem is that the ESP01 doesn't connect to the "localhost:1833" (that should be my Mosquitto address). I don't know what to do, am I missing something?

This line could be the problem? I didn't set a client name on NodeRed -------> if (mqttClient.connect("ESP8266Client"))

ESP sketch:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
    
const char* ssid         = "WifiNetworkname";
const char* password     = "password";
const char* mqttServer   = "localhost:1833";
const int   mqttPort     = 1883;
    
#define PUB_GPIO2_STATUS "state"
#define SUB_GPIO2_ACTION "state"
#define GPIO2_LED 2
     
WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(wifiClient);
     
void loop() {
  mqttClient.loop();
}
    
void initWifiStation() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);    
  Serial.print("\nConnecting to WiFi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);        
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(String("\nConnected to the WiFi network (") + ssid + ")" );
}
     
void initMQTTClient() {
  // Connecting to MQTT server
  mqttClient.setServer(mqttServer, mqttPort);
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    Serial.println(String("Connecting to MQTT (") + mqttServer + ")...");
    if (mqttClient.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
      Serial.println("MQTT client connected");  
    } else {
      Serial.print("\nFailed with state ");
      Serial.println(mqttClient.state());
      if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        initWifiStation();
      }
      delay(2000);
    }
  }
    
  // Declare Pub/Sub topics
  mqttClient.publish(PUB_GPIO2_STATUS, "Hello");
  mqttClient.subscribe(SUB_GPIO2_ACTION);
}
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // GPIO2 is set OUTPUT
  pinMode(GPIO2_LED, OUTPUT);
  initWifiStation();
  initMQTTClient();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Localhost` in the code on your ESP *is the ESP itself*. You are trying to connect from the ESP, to the ESP.

`Localhost` always refers to "this computer", just like the IP address 127.0.0.1 does.

"This computer" *as seen from the code on the ESP* is the ESP itself, and not the computer that is running the MQTT server.

Assuming the syntax is otherwise correct: in the line `const char* mqttServer = "localhost:1833";` you need to put in the IP address (or name) of the computer that runs your MQTT server instead of `localhost`. I don't know if you also need to change the port.

Comment: It's just fascinating and disappointing to me the sheer number of people who look at the word 'localhost' and never give it another thought.

Comment: You should also remove the `:1883` from the end of the `mqttServer` since the port is specified separately (1883 is the default MQTT port)

Comment: I'm on a mac and when i run from the terminal 'ifconfing' I should find the IP address of my computer. The thing is that when I put the IP address in the const char* mqttServer I'm not able to connect anyway